# How do I implement Objects.hashcode within java 1.6

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

I have some code as such:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendWidth);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendSideLength);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.thickness);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.innerRadius);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendAngle);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.kfactor);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendShortening);
    return hash;
}
```

and I'm looking to make this source work for 1.6

So far I've tried guava:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;


    Object[] objs = new Object[]{
        this.getPointND().getPoint()[0],
        this.getPointND().getPoint()[1],
        this.getPointND().getPoint()[2],
        this.getPointND().getPoint()[3],
        this.getPointND().getPoint()[4],
        this.kfactor,
        this.bendShortening
    };

    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(objs);

    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendWidth);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendSideLength);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.thickness);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.innerRadius);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendAngle);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.kfactor);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendShortening);
    return hash;
}
```

And I've tried a solution as so:

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;


        Object[] objs = new Object[]{
            this.getPointND().getPoint()[0],
            this.getPointND().getPoint()[1],
            this.getPointND().getPoint()[2],
            this.getPointND().getPoint()[3],
            this.getPointND().getPoint()[4],
            this.kfactor,
            this.bendShortening
        };

        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(objs);

        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendWidth);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendSideLength);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.thickness);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.innerRadius);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendAngle);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.kfactor);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendShortening);
        return hash;
    }
```

But still this test returns fails:

```
@Test
public void testHashCodeIsDifferentHashCode() {
    try {
        DataPoint pointOne = new DataPoint();
        pointOne.setBendAngle(new Double(1));
        pointOne.setBendShortening(new Double(1));
        pointOne.setBendSideLength(1);
        pointOne.setBendWidth(1);
        pointOne.setInnerRadius(1);
        pointOne.setKfactor(new Double(1));
        pointOne.setThickness(1);

        DataPoint pointTwo = new DataPoint();
        pointTwo.setBendAngle(0);
        pointTwo.setBendShortening(new Double(0));
        pointTwo.setBendSideLength(0);
        pointTwo.setBendWidth(0);
        pointTwo.setInnerRadius(0);
        pointTwo.setKfactor(new Double(0));
        pointTwo.setThickness(0);

        DataPoint pointThree = new DataPoint();
        pointThree.setBendAngle(Double.NaN);
        pointThree.setBendShortening(Double.NaN);
        pointThree.setBendSideLength(Double.NaN);
        pointThree.setBendWidth(Double.NaN);
        pointThree.setInnerRadius(Double.NaN);
        pointThree.setKfactor(Double.NaN);
        pointThree.setThickness(Double.NaN);

        Set<DataPoint> map = new HashSet<DataPoint>();
        map.add(pointOne);
        map.add(pointTwo);
        assert (map.size() == 2);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        assert false : "failed due to null";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        assert false : "failed, unknown error.";
    }
}
```

Have tried this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendWidth);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendSideLength);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.thickness);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.innerRadius);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendAngle);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.kfactor);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bendShortening);
    return hash;
}
```

```
public class Objects {

    public static int hashCode(Object object) {
        return object == null ? 0 : object.hashCode();
    }
}
```

My equals solution is as so:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof DataPoint) {
        DataPoint od = (DataPoint) obj;
        return (this.bendAngle == od.bendAngle)
                && (this.bendShortening == od.bendShortening)
                && (this.bendSideLength == od.bendSideLength)
                && (this.bendWidth == od.bendWidth)
                && (this.innerRadius == od.innerRadius)
                && (this.kfactor == od.kfactor)
                && (this.thickness == od.thickness);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nope, this was added in jdk 1.7. You will have to roll your own solution.

Comment: In any case your IDE of choice should have some intelligent "Generate equals() and hashcode()" function.

Comment: Note that, even for primitive-boxing wrapper-types like `Double`, the `==` notation denotes *reference*-equality (identity), not *structural* equality (equality of value). For example, `new Double(0.0) == new Double(0.0)` evaluates to `false`, because they are references to two distinct instances of `Double`. You must keep this in mind when writing your `equals` method.

Comment: @ruakh That was exactly the problem amigo! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equals method was the problem. a new Double(0.0) == new Double(0.0) evaluates to false.

Comment: Another "victory" for auto-unboxing wasting our time.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing in JDK 1.6, but it's utterly trivial to write it yourself:

```
public static int hashCode(Object object) {
    return object == null ? 0 : object.hashCode();
}
```

Or - preferrably, IMO - start using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) which has a familiar-looking [`Objects`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html) class. (It's not quite the same, as it only has the version taking an array via varargs, but that just means you can write your method in a single call.)

I suspect that you'll find that if you look closely at Guava, there are a bunch of useful things in there which you'll start using - I know I wouldn't want to write any signficant amount of Java code these days without Guava or something very similar.

If this were a dependency *just* for `Objects.hashCode` I'd just implement that method myself, but I'm sure there are other things you'll find useful.

Comment: @dah: Well you need to override `equals` as well - have you done that? And hash maps will only prevent duplicate *keys* - it's not clear whether you're using this for keys or values.

Comment: Sorry. I meant hash sets. I've added the solutions I've tried, as well as my equals routine to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is one option:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.asList(this.bendWidth, this.x, this.y).hashCode();
}
```

Is null safe, and generates a good hash code.  There is also an Objects class in quava:

```
com.google.common.base.Objects
```